# NavigationController Transparent And Background Image On Swift

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, swift2

I learning IOS Programming, When i create navigation controller, i have 2 kinds navigation, navigationbar with image background and transparent background:

first controller with transparent navigationBar background, and second controller use navigation with image background, but when i back from secondcontroller to firstcontroller, there is flash in navigationbar. how to fix it ?

[see that navbar, there is flash white whan back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THFFE.png)

Comment: How you are setting the background image and transparent bar? Can I see some code?

Comment: code here -> [See Code Here](http://pastebin.com/69DUhUZN)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add image in both navigation bar controller..but When you pop back from second to first just hide the image of first navigation bar...it might be helpful to you...!!